# Ensure statement is not optimized "away"

Tags: c#, .net, properties

I'm using an API where, unfortunately, calling a get property accessor has a side-effect. How can I ensure that:

```
public void Foo()
{
  var x = obj.TheProp; // is it guarnateed to be accessed?
}
```

isn't optimized away by the compiler?

Comment: I think the compiler looks to properties as method calls, so it can't "go away", but not 100% sure.

Comment: As an aside; usually, when people want this, it is because there is some subtle side-effect of the getter; IMO, it is much clearer to explicitly make it a method - then you can also just write: `obj.GetTheProp();` (and simply choose to ignore the return value). But IMO this is much clearer to the caller that side-effects should be expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That will not be optimized away - the getter is a method and will be invoked, although the JIT might choose to "inline" a lot of it if it is simple, perhaps eventually (and entirely theoretically) ending up with just a null-reference check if `TheProp` doesn't do anything particularly exciting. What *can* happen is that the "thing returned" (that the code stores into `x`) is eligible for garbage collection before the method ends; this is rarely an issue, except with things like an out-of-process mutex; in which case, you can do things like:

```
var x = obj.TheProp;
// long-running code here
GC.KeepAlive(x);
```

Note, however, that if `x` is value-typed, this will force it to be boxed, which is not ideal.

Emphasis, though: the above is *not* intended to ensure that `TheProp` is actually invoked; it is for a specific set of garbage-related scenarios.